# change site template to publishing (after provisioning a site with project template)

Tags: site-template

I am sure the answer is NO. but just want to confirm. Someone provisioned a site using project template then she realized she was supposed to use publishing template.

I think delete and re-create is the only option. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can enable the Office Publishing Infrastructure Site Collection and Site features to get the same effect.  This would give them both Project and Publishing features.

If the project features are not desired, then they could be deactivated but you might run into issues later with upgrades and such.  It would be best to delete the site and recreate it on the desired template.

Comment: Eric: Then you will get both Project + Publishing features. I think they just want publishing site (not project related stuff at all). So I guess delete and re-provisioned with publishing site template. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that would be the case, I'll edit my answer with something more applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the Publishing Feature independently of which site template you use, but in general the different templates create many lists and behaviours and activate features. It is so easy to create a site from a template that, unless there is a significant amount of content in the site, I would just start again.